# Creating a new version of Android app without overwriting

Tags: android, android-studio, version, updates

I want to clean up and add to an application I'm working on in Android Studio. Is there anyway to have my current version saved while being able to work on the new version without fear of permanently breaking anything? Do I just create a new file? Or is there some other way. I'm new to app development and haven't learned much about version control.

Comment: _"...and haven't learned much about version control"_ - now would seem to be the perfect opportunity!

Comment: If you don't want to or don't have the time to learn version control, you can make a copy for each version of your app. You will end up with a lot of copies (v1, v2, v3, ....), but they will be a safety net for your development. I used to do that 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Using VCS is the best way to do this, but that requires more learning, depending on what you'd be using for version control.

A short, factual answer to your question is that you can just make a copy of your project's folder (found in the AndroidStudioProjects folder), rename the copied project folder to something sensible, and then in Android Studio, choose New>>Import Project, and import the new folder.

I just tested this and, although inelegant, it appears to work fine.